# Datamapper resource becomes collection in session value

Tags: ruby, database, sinatra, session-cookies, datamapper

After running a function that (blah) returns a Datamapper object (LuckEvent), my code stores that in a Rack session. This is read in a HAML view, which consistently returns a DataMapper::Collection.
Code for getting the LuckEvent:

```
puts "|LX| Jumped, getting event"
session["lastLDEvent"] = ldg.get_event
puts "|LX| Jump event: #{session["lastLDEvent"].inspect}" #Consistently returns the right value.
```

Code for viewing it in HAML:

```
.w3-container.w3-pale-blue
  = session["lastLDEvent"].class if session["lastLDEvent"] #Consistently returns DataMapper::Collection.
```

Switching that to `.inspect` consistently returns [].

Comment: Are you storing it in the session and rendering it in a view within the same HTTP request or are you storing it in the session and then displaying it in the view in a later HTTP request?

Comment: After the first code block, a redirect happens and it gets rendered there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try casting the result of `get_event` to an `Array`. There might be an issue with storing `DataMapper::Collection` in the session.

```
session["lastLDEvent"] = ldg.get_event.to_a
```

If that doesn't work, you may need to store the IDs and then re-query the events.

```
session["lastLDEvent"] = ldg.get_event.map(&:id)
```

Comment: First dosen't work because to.a dosen't seem to work.